# Is there any solution to ClickAndWait problem

Tags: katalon-recorder

I try to test a webpage with **Katalon** Chrome plugin, but I stucked with a `button click`.

I tried to use `ClickAndWait` command to solve it.

My script try to click an inactive button and I can't configure to wait until the button get an active state.
What is the problem?

```
 click | xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='name'])[1]/following::label[1] |
```

click | //textarea | 
type | //textarea | 1

clickAndWait | xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='name'])[1]/following::button[1] | 3000
click | xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='name2'])[1]/following::button[1] |

If I add a text to textcontent the button state remove the disable state.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @lahimadhe : I add the code sample. The button is visible but not clickable. I try to do this with chromeplugin, there was no clickable funcion.